# How to use useCallback inside custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, callback

got little issue here. I'm exporting a custom hook, which uses other hooks, but I get "Unhandled Rejection (Error): Invalid hook call..." Error. Looks like I'm not doing something wrong... I'm using hook inside hook, so why is this error being thrown?

```
const customHook = async () => {
const { values } = useValues()

const testCallback = useCallback(async () => {
    const value = values

    return value
}, [value])

 return testCallback 
}

export default customHook
```

Comment: `testCallback` is `async` so it returns a promise. Consumers should be prepared to catch any potential Promise rejections.

Comment: Your custom hook should start with "use" and not be async https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

Comment: Thanks for answers! Removed async, but still getting somehow:

 Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: Where/how is `customHook` used? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example And as Dennis points, it should be renamed `useCustomHook`.

Comment: Thanks for everyone greafully. I realised that this custom hook was used in other hooks, like useMemo... that's also react hooks rules violation. So exported that useCallback function from custom hook and used it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue can be resolved by just changing the case of your component's name, try renaming it to "CustomHook". There's a rule with react hooks that you can not call use hook inside a function or component whose name is in Camel Case.